# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null in as3 while playing VPAID Ads in adobe player

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, vast

We have VAST tags which returns VPAID Ads and we developed plugin similar to OVA using actionscript3 so that Ad should be displayed in the adobe player using our developed plugin. But everytime it gives error as

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.

And while debugging it gets initialized, started and getting loaded but after that it shows this error. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, usually when you develop something in actionscript that needs to load assets or put something in the DisplayList such as `Sprite`, you have to wait for the `Stage` to be ready. I usually do this in the `Main` class (or the one linked in the .fla file) so this way the code knows when it is proper to load the assets into the `DisplayList`

```
public class Main extends Sprite {
  public function Main():void{
    init();
    if (stage != null){
  addedToStage();
    }else{
      addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    }
  }
  private function addedToStage(e:Event = null):void {
    //entry point
  }
  private function init():void{
    //here you initialize your variables
  }
}
```

Sometimes the `Stage` will be ready, sometimes the file is a bit too heavy and it takes time to load, so we put a listener to wait. If you do it locally, it will not fail, but as soon as you put it on line (website), you will find this discrepancy.

Other thing you could try is to load that swf (ad) into a `Loader`

```
_loader = new Loader();
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteContentLoaderInfo);
```

and in the function onCompleteContentLoaderInfo check for `_loader.content;` once loaded it is technically a potencial SWF, so you can then check for its properties, and verify that its stage is available (not null).

When you work on line you always need to check for listeners if something is going to be loaded, it is sometimes tricky; maybe you already know that, but the first listener to check for `Stage` is very important.